# Create an input text box depending on the radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm new to jquery and im wondering how will I generate a new input text box depending on the value of a radio button. Example if I click on radio button number 2 that has a value of '2' the number of input text boxes I have will be two; when I click radio button number 3 I'll have a total of 3 input text boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var this_index_limit = parseInt($(this).val());
    for(var i = 0; i < this_index_limit; i++) {
       if(!$('#text_box_' + i).length) {
          $('<input id="text_box_' + i + '" type="text"/>').appendTo($(this).parent());
       }
       else if($('#text_box_' + i).is(':hidden')) {
          $('#text_box_' + i).show();
       }
    }

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
       var split_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
       if(!split_id.length) return; //from each function, not the outer click function.
       var index = parseInt(split_id[2]);
       if(index >= this_index_limit) {
           $(this).hide();
       }
    });
});
```

### jsFiddle example

Comment: @Avenson, I actually worked on this answer for 5 minutes... You're welcome.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do this for hours already till I finally decided to ask for help. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, I hope you wont mind me askin another favor from you. My problem is that how will I make a multi level field generator depending on the radio buttons value. I recycled your code, but its not working the way its supposed to. Hope you could help me with this. Thanks :) Please check the code at http://jsfiddle.net/masterhopia316/kXG5t/